# how to write SQL Query for 3 column values with different dates for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a customer requirement, where they need the following data:

- Total amt unpaid until 30/06/14
- Total amt deducted from 01/04/2013 - 29/02/2014
- Total amt paid from 01/07/2013 - 29/01/2014

The table `Transactions` contains the following:

> Date Paid, Amount Paid, AccountNumber, EmployeeId

These maybe or may not be in the same table, which I will figure out. However, each column may differ. How to write a query for this kind of complexity :( Can someone please help me with an example of same type.

Comment: Without some some schema info this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Andreas: I already said you can use a sample table with 3 different amount columns. Can you not make it?

Comment: At negative voters or closers, have you not encountered such situations? lol

Comment: `Date Paid, Amount Paid, AccountNumber, EmployeeId` is a good start. I could give you a sketch of a query for amount paid in a date range. Is there a similar table for deducted amount and unpaid amount? If so, what do they look like?

Comment: If you took the time to put together an sqlfiddle, I bet the solutions would flow quite nicely.

Comment: @Andreas: I have modified my query, can you write the solution?

Comment: @Andreas: I just discussed with my team mate, the query is not so simple as we think although customer requirements are the one I specified above. I have to join few tables, which I can do very well, however, I do not know how to check for null if null then another column, and the corresponding column in another table

Comment: @Andreas, there is a column called EffectiveDate, and I want to check if the value is not null then take this value from this table "table 1" and the corresponding EffectiveAmount from "table 2" and if the value of EffectiveDate is Null then ActualDate should be considered from "table 1" and the corresponding ActualAmount from "table 2"

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know how to check for null if null then another column, and the corresponding column in another table

I think the keyword you are looking for is "coalesce":

```
create table othertable(id int primary key identity, usethiscolumnwhennull varchar(255));
create table mytable(id int primary key identity, othertable_id int references othertable(id), description varchar(255), thiscolumnissometimesnull varchar(255));

insert into othertable(usethiscolumnwhennull) values ('othertable 1'),('othertable 2');
insert into mytable(othertable_id,description,thiscolumnissometimesnull) values (1,'no nulls here','mytable 1'),(1,'there is a null! use the value from othertable',null);

select description, coalesce(m.thiscolumnissometimesnull,o.usethiscolumnwhennull) from mytable m join othertable o on m.othertable_id=o.id
```

Comment: Andreas, thank you very much, looks good to me, however, I need to use the other logics; my team mate told me that it can not be made in single query but subqueries for those 3 columns with different conditions. Any insight on that? Also all those 3 columns are in different tables :(

Comment: I would avoid subselects. Join the tables an use a case statement to grab data from the right column. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Sad, I do not understand how to do this, but let me take sometime to slowly figure out on what I need to do. :) :) Keep you posted, thank you very much